# my htaccess does not affect the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^log-in/?$    login.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "pet-care"
RewriteRule    ^login/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    login.php?task=$1    [NC,L]    # Process parrots
```

My .htaccess file contains this, but its not affecting the url.
I checked the apache config and changed AllowOverride from None to All , restarted the apache server but it still wont work.
Does anybody know how to fix this ?

Comment: Try using `RewriteCond`

Comment: This rule is only doing internal routing and won't redirect (URLs won't change in browser). What are you requirements.

Comment: I want the url's to be changed in the browser, how do I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these right below `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+login\.php\?task=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /login/%1/? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+login\.php($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /log-in/ [L,R]
```

Note that you're changing your relative URL base, so all your relative links will be broken. In order to fix that, you'll need to add a base in your page headers:

```
<base href="/" />
```